# Combine 2 SOQL to limit SOQL 101 error

Tags: apex, soql

I am getting 101 error and trying to limit the total number of queries been executed.
I know that SOQL query can be optimized to single if or condition been there.I am trying to optimize below SOQL to single But unable to do so.

```
[Select Name, Id, CurrencyISOCode, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, Product2.Name,
from PriceBookEntry where IsActive = true 
AND Product2.IsSFA_PRM_Product__c = true
AND Product2.Platform_Group__c=:Listreturn[0].PricebookEntry.Product2.PlatGrp
AND CurrencyISOCode=:Listreturn[0].CurrencyISOCode 
AND Pricebook2.IsActive = true 
AND Pricebook2Id=:customsetting.PriceBookId
AND priceBook2.isStandard = false
AND Product2.Product_Platform__c=:restRequest.Platform limit 1];
```

--

```
[Select Name, Id, CurrencyISOCode, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, Product2.Name, Product2.ProductGroup,
Product2.Family
from PriceBookEntry where IsActive = true 
AND CurrencyISOCode=:Listreturn[0].CurrencyISOCode 
AND Pricebook2.IsActive = true 
AND Pricebook2Id=:customsetting.PriceBookId
AND priceBook2.isStandard = false
AND Product2.Family= :systemLabel limit 1];
```

Comment: These two queries are not your main problem. Its where and how they are used. Combining them into a single query will only allow you to process 100 iterations instead of 50 yet the main problem will still exist. You need to figure out why these queries are being executed multiple times and refactor so they are only executed once.

Comment: @Eric I have used Limits.getLimitQueries and other SOQL queries methods and these queries are been used exactly once.However , there are various trigger which works behind the same and those cannot be optimized , Therefore was looking one by one for option to optimize the queries

Comment: Then combining them will only allow you to process 1 more record. Again, you need to find the real issue rather than spend time optimizing to gain 1 additional record. Not trying to be obtuse, just trying to get you focused in the right direction. unfortunately we do not have enough information to help you out in that case. The only way to optimized these queries would be to remove the unique filters for each query and use code to segment the results into appropriate collections